# Sending an argument to a contract method with sendTransaction

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, contract-development, web3js, truffle

I'm using the truffle console to test my contract, but I'm having a trouble passing an argument. For example, I have a method like this

```
function sendEtherTo(address addr) public payable {
   require(addr != 0x0);
   require(msg.value > 0);
   addr.transfer(msg.value);
}
```

I'm trying to use `sendTransaction` but can't figure out how to pass in the argument.

This:

```
 web3.eth.sendTransaction({from: web3.eth.accounts[1], to: myContract.address, data: myContract.sendEtherTo.sendTransaction(web3.eth.accounts[2]), value: web3.toWei(10, "finney")})
```

Results in my testrpc crashing with an error in truffle saying

```
Error: Invalid JSON RPC response: undefined
```

I've tried the following which I've done in web3 successfully

```
web3.eth.sendTransaction({from: web3.eth.accounts[1], to: myContract.address, data: myContract['sendEtherTo'].getData(web3.eth.accounts[2]), value: web3.toWei(10, "finney")})
```

but this tells me that `getData` is undefined

Comment: How do you create `myContract`? If you call `myContract.sendEtherTo()` directly does it work?

Comment: AFAIK sendTransaction can't invoke a method, it can invoke a contract. Then this contract may send message (i.e. call a method) to another contract,

Comment: @Nulik You are wrong. To use sendTransaction you need to encode the function call inside the data field.

Answer (score 1):

Truffle wraps contracts with a custom object that doesn't provide `getData`, but we can use the `request` method to obtain the parameters for `sendTransaction`.

```
const MyContract = artifacts.require('MyContract');

contract('MyContract', function(accounts) {
  it('Call with sendTransaction', async () => {
    const myContract = await MyContract.deployed();

    // We want to call foo(23) on myContract
    const data = myContract.foo.request(23);

    // Here data.params[0].data contains the parameters to the call

    const txhash = web3.eth.sendTransaction({ 
      from: accounts[0], 
      to: myContract.address, 
      value: 1, 
      data: data.params[0].data
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this out tonight to see how it works. What's the JS framework this example is using? I've been out of the loop in the JS world for a while

Comment: This is a unit test for Truffle.